# how to write a docviewer functional components the path showing the C:\\fakepath\\documents.docx' how to clear this error

Tags: reactjs, state

```
const HandleFileUpdates = (e) => {
    let selectedFiles ={uri:e.target.value}
        setUploadFile(selectedFiles)
        
  }

  
  console.log("uploadfile", uploadFile)

  const HandleViewDoc = () => {
  
      if(uploadFile){
        setFileview(uploadFile)
      }
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Form>

        <h2>uploadfile:</h2>
        <Input type="file" className="form-control" onChange={HandleFileUpdates}></Input>
        <Button className="btn btn-success" type="submit" onClick={() => HandleViewDoc}>view </Button>
      </Form>
      {fileveiw?
      <DocViewer
        pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
        documents={fileveiw}
        style={{ height: 500 }}
      />:""}
    </div>
  )
```

how to get a doc view on this code check and correct my code